# Google Apps Script UrlFetchApp.fetch() truncating the responseText

Tags: google-apps-script

When calling UrlFetchApp.fetch() and the response is large (a json containing around 2000 itens with 400 characters each item), the responseText is getting truncated. The length of the response is supposed to be around 800.000 characters, but the size of the response is 588.541 characters (around 500kb). Are there any limits on urlFetch response size?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That quota is not published (see  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) but you should get paginated data anyways. Apps script wont give you enough ram or time to process that much data.
If that url doesnt suport paging you are out of luck.

Comment: Since we are in charge of the backend, there are some alternatives to consider to deal with this limitation. The problem is that we don't know if its really a quota limit. If so, the limit is really 500kb? Why just a data truncation without any warning or exception? With a little more upfront information we can take the best action, like pagination, limitations to our own services and so on, or even choose not to provide some gas integration features before the system goes to production.