# How can I find a URL called [link] inside any block of HTML?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm writing a script to rewrite Reddit's RSS feeds. The script needs to find a URL named `[link]` inside a block of HTML that contains other URLs. The HTML is contained in an XML element called `<description>`.

Here are three examples of the `<description>` element I need to parse and the `[link]` I would need to get. Note that each description element has a different HTML layout. There could be other layouts I have yet to encounter so the solution needs to be generic.

---

**First example:**

```
<description>submitted by &lt;a href=&#34;http://www.reddit.com/user/wildlyinaccurate&#34;&gt; wildlyinaccurate &lt;/a&gt; &lt;br/&gt; &lt;a href=&#34;http://wildlyinaccurate.com/a-hackers-guide-to-git&#34;&gt;[link]&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/26jvl7/a_hackers_guide_to_git/"&gt;[66 comments]&lt;/a&gt;</description>
```

The `[link]` is: http://wildlyinaccurate.com/a-hackers-guide-to-git

---

**Second example:**

```
<description>&lt;!-- SC_OFF --&gt;&lt;div class=&#34;md&#34;&gt;&lt;p&gt;I work a support role at a company where I primarily fix issues our customers our experiencing with our software, which is a browser based application written primarily in javascript. I&amp;#39;ve been doing this for 2 years, but I want to take it to the next level (with the long term goal being that I become proficient enough to call myself a developer). I&amp;#39;ve been reading &amp;quot;Javascript The Definitive Guide&amp;quot; by O&amp;#39;Reilly but I was wondering if any of you more experienced users out there had some tips on taking it to the next level. Should I start incorporating some PHP and Jquery into my learning? Side projects on my spare time? Any good online resources? Etc. &lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;Thanks! &lt;/p&gt; &lt;/div&gt;&lt;!-- SC_ON --&gt; submitted by &lt;a href=&#34;http://www.reddit.com/user/56killa&#34;&gt; 56killa &lt;/a&gt; &lt;br/&gt; &lt;a href=&#34;http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/26nduc/i_want_to_become_more_experienced_with_javascript/&#34;&gt;[link]&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/26nduc/i_want_to_become_more_experienced_with_javascript/"&gt;[4 comments]&lt;/a&gt;</description>
```

The `[link]` is: http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/26nduc/i_want_to_become_more_experienced_with_javascript/

---

**Third example:**

```
<description>&lt;table&gt; &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt; &lt;a href=&#34;http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/26o1by/watch_dogs_take_on_window_reflections/&#34;&gt;&lt;img src=&#34;http://f.thumbs.redditmedia.com/oZ3s8lFZt_3YRxgM.jpg&#34; alt=&#34;Watch Dogs take on window reflections&#34; title=&#34;Watch Dogs take on window reflections&#34; /&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt; submitted by &lt;a href=&#34;http://www.reddit.com/user/OutoflurkintoLight&#34;&gt; OutoflurkintoLight &lt;/a&gt; to &lt;a href=&#34;http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/&#34;&gt; gaming&lt;/a&gt; &lt;br/&gt; &lt;a href=&#34;https://i.stack.imgur.com/afFg7.jpg&#34;&gt;[link]&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/26o1by/watch_dogs_take_on_window_reflections/"&gt;[712 comments]&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;</description>
```

The `[link]` is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/afFg7.jpg

---

**Update:** My actual parsing code:

```
// Temporary program entry point for quick testing
function main()
{
  // This could be any public sub-reddit RSS feed.
  var rss = parseFeed("http://www.reddit.com/.rss");
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(rss).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.RSS);
}

// Actual program entry point when published
function doGet(e) {
    var feed_url = e.queryString ? e.queryString : "http://www.reddit.com/.rss";
    var rss = parseFeed(feed_url);  
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(rss).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.RSS);
}


// Returns the rewritten XML feed
function parseFeed(url)
{
  try {
    // Fetch the XML
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var xml = response.getContentText();
    var doc = XmlService.parse(xml);
    var root = doc.getRootElement();

    // Get an array of all items in the feed.
    var items = root.getChildren("channel")[0].getChildren("item");

    // Loop over the items, getting the [link] for each one.
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var description = items[i].getChild("description");

      var link = getLink(description.getText());
      Logger.log( link );

      // ... Do other stuff with XML ...
    }

    return XmlService.getRawFormat().format(doc);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error.toString());
  }
}

function getLink(description) {
    // get the link from description and return it.
    return "not implemented";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT 2

Ok. Final answer:

```
// Temporary program entry point for quick testing
function main()
{
  // This could be any public sub-reddit RSS feed.
  var rss = parseFeed("http://www.reddit.com/.rss");
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(rss).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.RSS);
}

// Actual program entry point when published
function doGet(e) {
    var feed_url = e.queryString ? e.queryString : "http://www.reddit.com/.rss";
    var rss = parseFeed(feed_url);  
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(rss).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.RSS);
}


// Returns the rewritten XML feed
function parseFeed(url)
{
  try {
    // Fetch the XML
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var xml = response.getContentText();
    var doc = XmlService.parse(xml);
    var root = doc.getRootElement();

    // Get an array of all items in the feed.
    var items = root.getChildren("channel")[0].getChildren("item");

    // Loop over the items, getting the [link] for each one.
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var description = items[i].getChild("description");

      var link = getLink(description.getText());
      Logger.log( link );

      // ... Do other stuff with XML ...
    }

    return XmlService.getRawFormat().format(doc);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error.toString());
  }
}


function getLink(str) {

  var doc = XmlService.parse("<document>"+str+"</document>");
  var elements = doc.getRootElement().getDescendants()

  // for each descendant, check to see if it is an <a> tag
  // if it is, check to see if it contains "[link]"
  // if it does, get the href and return

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var entry = elements[i].asElement();
    if(entry != null && entry.getName() === "a") {
      var href = entry.getAttribute('href')
      var text = entry.getText();
      if(text == "[link]" && href != null){
        var link = href.getValue();
        return link;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### EDIT

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857613/google-apps-script-urlfetchapp-fetch-truncating-the-responsetext), Google Apps Script actually has a limit to how much data it will return from a URL request. You've run up against that limit, and so you're getting a bunch of incomplete XML that can't be parsed.

---

It seems you'll have to use the built in XML functions to do the work for you.

- load up your RSS
- decode the html entities
- run the html through the XML parser
- get the <a> tags
- find the one with [link] in the text
- grab its href

This should work

```
function getLink(str) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var decode = XmlService.parse(str);
  var decoded = decode.getRootElement().getText();

  var doc = XmlService.parse(decoded);
  var entries = doc.getDescendants();


  for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    var entry = entries[i].asElement();

    if(entry != null && entry.getName() === "a") {
      var href = entry.getAttribute('href')
      var text = entry.getText();
      if(text === "[link]" && href != null){
        var link = href.getValue();
        Logger.log(link);
        return link;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I copy/pasted your function into my script, but it fails to parse the first few `<description>` elements, returning nothing, then eventually throws an exception :(  I've updated the question to show real code and added another example case any answer would need to handle.

Comment: Well, it looks like you've got a problem. Google apps script has a quota for how much data it'll actually return when you run a network request. Reddit's RSS feed is too long for it, and so it returns a truncated result. I'll update my answer with some code that should work for all your examples, but apps script may not be the way to go for your project. I'd recommend using Node.js and Cheerio to do web scraping, seeing as you're already working with JavaScript.

Comment: I can fetch and log the entire RSS feed and see no truncation.

Comment: Huh, that's weird. It definitely cuts off when I log it. It throws Exception: Error on line -1: Premature end of file when I  parse it, I assume it hits the truncated portion and gives up.

Comment: My previous statement is incorrect; I can't log it in full. The Logger is limited to the number of characters it will print. However, when published and run, the script downloads and prints the XML exactly as retrieved, and it's not truncated at all.

Comment: The link about data limits hints the limit is around 500k. The largest RSS feed I've gotten back from Reddit so far is only 42k.

Comment: Excellent! I did not know of the `.getDecendants()` function. I would give you many more upvotes if I could. Thank you for sticking around and helping me solve the problem. :)